# taking input from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to take input from a text file into a 3d matrix in matlab
My text file is like

4 //size of dimension 1 of the 3d matrix

5 //size of dimension 2 of the 3d matrix

6 //size of dimension 3 of the 3d matrix

then 4*5 = 20 lines of 6 values each as the values of the 3d matrix

can anyone suggest me how to take the input in matlab by creating a 3d matrix in it.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the data from a file, then use reshape.  For example:

```
X = load(filename); %% loads your data into a 20x6 matrix
Y = reshape(X, 4, 5, 6);
```

You might have to shuffle the order of the dimensions to get what you want, since you didn't mention how you wanted the 20 rows to be broken up for the first two dimensions.